# Enviar e-mail com anexo enviado por input

Tags: php, upload, email, yii

Tenho um site PHP com um formulário de contacto que permite fazer upload de um ficheiro. Esse ficheiro deve depois ser enviado anexado num e-mail juntamente com os outros dados. O e-mail não está a ser recebido, embora receba a mensagem de confirmação de envio. Também não está em pastas de spam. Já experimentei o e-mail da empresa, o GMail e o Hotmail.

Existe um ficheiro PHP com o HTML que depois faz um post (jQuery e AJAX) para um ficheiro PHP de script. Nesse ficheiro de script é que é feito o envio de email. Sei que a função de envio está a ser executada porque recebo mensagem dela.

código HTML:

```
    <div id="inscreverOportunidade" class="hideform inscreverOportunidade" style="display:none;">
        <div id="boxForm">
            <div class="formProf">
                    <div style="width:100%;" class="big-new-close" onclick="javascript:showForm('');"><span>X</span></div>
                    <div class="to">
                        <div class="small-text"> NOME*</div>
                        <input type="text" required="true" class="input-text" value="" id="NomeO" name="NomeO" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                                    this.value = '';
                                }">
                    </div>
                    <div class="to email">
                        <div class="small-text">  EMAIL*</div>
                        <input type="email" required="true" class="text" value="" id="EmailO" name="EmailO" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                                    this.value = '';
                                }" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="to">
                        <div class="small-text"> CONTACTO*</div>
                        <input type="text" required="true" class="input-text" value="" id="ContactoO" name="ContactoO" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                                    this.value = '';
                                }">
                    </div>
                    <div class="to email">
                        <div class="small-text">  LOCALIDADE*</div>
                        <input type="text" required="true" class="text" value="" id="LocalidadeO" name="LocalidadeO" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                                    this.value = '';
                                }" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="to">
                        <div class="small-text"> PROFISSÃO*</div>
                        <input type="text" required="true" class="input-text" value="" id="ProfissaoO" name="ProfissaoO" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                                    this.value = '';
                                }">
                    </div>
                    <div class="to email">
                        <div class="small-text">  ANEXAR CURRÍCULO*</div>
                        <input type="file" required="true" name="CV" id="CV" class="text" accept=".docx, .doc, .pdf">
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">Os campos marcados com * são de preenchimento obrigatório</div>
                    <div class="submit-curriculo"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Inscrever" onclick="javascript:sendFormRegO();
                            return false;"></div>
            </div> <!--end formProf-->
        </div> <!--end boxForm-->
    </div>
    <script>
        function sendFormRegO()
        {
            var proceed = true;
            //simple validation at client's end
            //loop through each field and we simply change border color to red for invalid fields       
            $("#inscreverOportunidade input[required=true]").each(function(){
                $(this).css('border-color',''); 
                if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
                    $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                    proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
                }
                //check invalid email
                var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
                if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
                    $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                    proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
                }   
            });

            if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
            {
               //data to be sent to server         
                var m_data = new FormData();    
                m_data.append( 'nome', $('input[name=NomeO]').val());
                m_data.append( 'email', $('input[name=EmailO]').val());
                m_data.append( 'contacto', $('input[name=ContactoO]').val());
                m_data.append( 'localidade', $('input[name=LocalidadeO]').val());
                m_data.append( 'profissao', $('input[name=ProfissaoO]').val());
                m_data.append( 'file', $('input[name=CV]')[0].files[0]);

                //instead of $.post() we are using $.ajax()
                //that's because $.ajax() has more options and flexibly.
                $.ajax({
                  url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('site/inscricaooportunidade'); ?>',
                  data: m_data,
                  processData: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  type: 'POST',
                  dataType:'json',
                  success: function(response){
                      alert(response.text);
                     //load json data from server and output message     
                    if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
                        output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
                    }else{
                        output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                    }
                  }
                });         
            }
        }
        </script>
```

código PHP:

```
    public function actionInscricaoOportunidade()
    {

        //if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
        if($_POST)
        {

            //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
            if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
                $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
                    'type'=>'error',
                    'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
                ));
                die($output); //exit script outputting json data
            }

            //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
            $nome      = filter_var($_POST['nome'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $email     = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            $contacto   = filter_var($_POST['contacto'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $localidade   = filter_var($_POST['localidade'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $profissao        = filter_var($_POST['profissao'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

            //$message->addTo(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail']);
            $to_email       = "diogo.alexandre.86@live.com.pt";
            $from_email     = $email;

            //email body
            $message_body = "Foi efectuada uma nova inscrição na oportunidade XXX com os seguintes dados:<br /><br />";
            $message_body .= "<strong>NOME:</strong> " . $nome . "<br />";
            $message_body .= "<strong>EMAIL:</strong> " . $email . "<br />";
            $message_body .= "<strong>CONTACTO:</strong> " . $contacto . "<br />";
            $message_body .= "<strong>Localidade:</strong> " . $localidade . "<br />";
            $message_body .= "<strong>Profissão:</strong> " . $profissao . "<br /><br />";
            $message_body .= "<strong>O Curriculo do candidato encontra-se anexado a este email</strong>";

            ### Attachment Preparation ###
            $file_attached = false;
            if(isset($_FILES['file'])) //check uploaded file
            {
                //get file details we need
                $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                $file_name        = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                $file_size        = $_FILES['file']['size'];
                $file_type        = $_FILES['file']['type'];
                $file_error       = $_FILES['file']['error'];

                //exit script and output error if we encounter any
                if($file_error>0)
                {
                    $mymsg = array( 
                    1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini", 
                    2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form", 
                    3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded", 
                    4=>"No file was uploaded", 
                    6=>"Missing a temporary folder" ); 

                    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $mymsg[$file_error]));
                    die($output); 
                }

                //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
                $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
                $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
                fclose($handle);
                $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
                //now we know we have the file for attachment, set $file_attached to true
                $file_attached = true;
            }

            if($file_attached) //continue if we have the file
            {
                # Mail headers should work with most clients
                $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers = "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\r\n";
                $headers .= "From: ".$from_email."\r\n";
                $headers .= "Subject: Confirmação de Inscricao - Oportunidade\r\n";
                $headers .= "Reply-To: " .$email. "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=".md5('boundary1')."\r\n\r\n";

                $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;  boundary=".md5('boundary2')."\r\n\r\n";

                $headers .= "--".md5('boundary2')."\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
                $headers .= $message_body."\r\n\r\n";

                $headers .= "--".md5('boundary2')."--\r\n";
                $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type:  ".$file_type."; ";
                $headers .= "name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Disposition:attachment; ";
                $headers .= "filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
                $headers .= "X-Attachment-Id:".rand(1000,9000)."\r\n\r\n";
                $headers .= $encoded_content."\r\n";
                $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."--";
            }else{
                //proceed with PHP email.
                $headers = 'From: '.$nome.'' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            }
            $send_mail = mail($to_email, "Confirmação de Inscricao - Oportunidade", $message_body, $headers);

            if(!$send_mail)
            {
                //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
                $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
                die($output);
            }else{
                $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$nome .' Thank you for your email'));
                die($output);
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: voce poderia utilizar esta extenção http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimailer/ que ja tem o que voce quer de uma forma pratica

Comment: Eu tentei usar também o yiimailer, que estava implementado por quem desenvolveu o projecto anteriormente, mas não estava a funcionar e não consegui corrigir. Nunca trabalhei com a plataforma Yii antes, e o meu conhecimento de PHP é mesmo muito pouco

Comment: se o conhecimento é pouco te aconcelho a estudar muito entrar em um framework sem o conhecimento devido é bem complicado

Comment: É o que tenho feito, mas esta questão é algo urgente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom... Aqui um codigo que eu fiz na França... 14 anos atrais (o tempo...). Funciona. 
Não tenho tempo para traduzir, mas e muito facil entender:

```
<?php

/*=============================================*/
/* ENVOI D'UN MAIL AVEC FICHIER JOINT EVENTUEL */
/*          PL Lamballais - PARX 2000          */
/*=============================================*/

/* Fichier: php.inc/send_mail.php3      */
/* Version 1.00 du 18/02/2000           */
/* Version 1.01 du 04/03/2000 Ajout de charset et du */
/* type MIME de l'envoi sans fichier joint pour avoir les accents. */

/* $dbug            => 0 = normal, 1 débug, donc on affiche les     infos. */
/* $mail_dest       => adresse email destination */
/* $mail_exp        => adresse email  expéditeur */
/* $mail_subject    => sujet du message */
/* $mail_msg        => corps du message */
/* $file_path       => chemin complet du fichier à joindre (rien si pas de fichier) */
/* $file_name       => nom du fichier devant apparaitre comme nom de pièce jointe */
/* $file_type       => type MIME du fichier à joindre */

function send_mail($dbug, $mail_dest,$mail_exp,$mail_subject,$mail_msg,$file_path,$file_name,$file_type)
{

if ($dbug == 1)
    {
        echo "Routine send_mail(). Mode débuggage<br />\n";
        echo "mail_dest = ".$mail_dest."<br />\n";
        echo "mail_exp = ".$mail_exp."<br />\n";
        echo "mail_subject = ".$mail_subject."<br />\n";
        echo "mail_msg = ".$mail_msg."<br />\n";
        echo "file_path = ".$file_path."<br />\n";
        echo "file_name = ".$file_name."<br />\n";
        echo "file_type = ".$file_type."<br     />\n";                                          
    }



/* Définition des éléments d'en-tête du mail */
/* Ce sont les éléments par défaut donc sans fichier joint */
    $boundary="-----------------kjbsdf9873987348735";
    $MIME = "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type:text/plain;\n\tcharset=\"utf-8\"\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
    $startMsg = "";
    $ending = "";


/*= Préparation du début du message =*/

    $hold_message = $mail_msg."\n\n";

/*= S'il y a un fichier, on l'encode =*/
    if ($file_path != "")
    {

    /* Vérifions l'existence de ce fichier */
    $tst = file_exists($file_path);
    if ($tst == false)
        {
            if ($dbug == 1)
                {
                    echo "== Erreur: le fichier ".$file_path." est introuvable.<br />\n";                   
            }   
        }
    else
        {
        $fp=fopen($file_path,"r");                      /* Ouvre le fichier */
        $in = fread( $fp, filesize( $file_path));       /* Lecture des données */
        fclose( $fp );                                  /* Fermeture fichier */
        $data_encode= chunk_split(base64_encode($in));  /* Encodage */

        if ($dbug == 1)
            {
                $taille = strlen($data_encode);
                echo "Taille des données Base64 : ".$taille."<br />\n";

            }

    /* Puisqu'il y a un fichier joint, on change le début et la fin du message */
        $startMsg = "\n--$boundary\nContent-Type:text/plain;\n\tcharset=\"utf-8\"\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
        $ending = "\n--$boundary--";

        $MIME = "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type:multipart/mixed;\n\tboundary=\"$boundary\"\n\nThis is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n";
        $hold_message = $hold_message."\n--$boundary\nContent-Type:".$file_type.";\n\tname=\"$file_name\"\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\nContent-Disposition: inline;\n\tfilename=\"$file_name\"\n\n$data_encode";
        }
    }

/*= La préparation est terminée, nous envoyons le message =*/
    $hold_from = "From: ".$mail_exp."\n".$MIME."\n";

    $hold_message = $startMsg.$hold_message.$ending;

    mail( $mail_dest, $mail_subject, $hold_message, $hold_from );
}
?>
```

Este codigo e usado aqui: http://www.ansb-brasil.org/trab_conosco/trab_conosco.php

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa converter o arquivo para um arquivo para um mime type do SwiftMailer `Swift_Mime_MimeEntity` type. `CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('fileupload')` returns a [CUploadedFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.0/CUploadedFile) class, que SwiftMailer não sabe como lidar. Mais informações em [Swift attachments here](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html).

Eu não testei isso, mas você vai precisar fazer algo parecido com isto:

```
$uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('fileupload'); // get the CUploadedFile
$uploadedFileName = $uploadedFile->tempName; // will be something like 'myfile.jpg'
$swiftAttachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($uploadedFileName); // create a Swift Attachment
$this->email->attach($swiftAttachment); // now attach the correct type
```

Boa sorte

Comment: Como usaria isto `getInstanceByName('fileupload')` no meu código? Desculpe mas tenho muito pouca prática em PHP. Já tinha visto esta solução na versão inglesa...

Comment: da uma pesquisada http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.0/CUploadedFile ali voce encontra um pouco mais de informação ... ou ate mesmo nos outros links que te mandei

Comment: Eu entendi bastante bem a informação nestes links que me enviaste, mas eu quero enviar um anexo que é feito upload pelo form de contacto. Não quero enviar um ficheiro que já esteja no servidor, nem quero fazer upload para o servidor primeiro, para depois anexar o ficheiro ao email. Quero que o utilizador defina qual o ficheiro a enviar, e que esse ficheiro seja enviado por email juntamente com as outras informações de contacto, sem ter que ficar no servidor.

Comment: primeiro voce move para o servidor, envia o email, depois apaga ele simples

Comment: Não há forma de fazer isso directamente?

Comment: nunca precisei fazer isso diretamente ... acho que não tem como nao mas assim o arquivo sobe para um tmp manda direto de la e pronto nao tem esquema

Comment: Nao precisa apagar: quando vc usa um input file, o ficheiro e salvo no servidor mas vai ser automaticamente destruido quando a script vai terminar (e por isso que devemos copiar ele usando move_uploaded_file para usar ele depois). Então, se, dentro do seu script, vc envia direitamente o documento recebido, sem user move_uploaded_file() ao fim do script, este documento vai desaparecer.

Comment: perfeito @Peter